# Regular Expression with odd number of 1's and at least one 0

Tags: regex, regular-language

I am designing a regular expression with an odd number of 1's and at least one 0.
Set of strings over {0,1}

So far I have this:

```
0+1(0+10+1)*0+
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, as long as there is at least one 0

Comment: Using pen and paper, DFA

Comment: ▲ for unique question. Give some valid examples please.

Comment: The regex would be: `^(0?(?:0*10*10*)*10?)$` for a regex tool. I'll see how to convert it to a valid NFA/DFA.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [deterministic finite automaton (DFA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton) would be

[image]

while following the steps described [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2016/how-to-convert-finite-automata-to-regular-expressions), I came up with

`00*1(11)*0*+1(11)*00*`